# No query plan for procedure in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-execution-plan

We have a SQL Server DB with 150-200 stored procs, all of which produce a viewable query plan in sys.dm_exec_query_plan except for one.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189747.aspx:

> Under the following conditions, no Showplan output is returned in the query_plan column of the returned table for sys.dm_exec_query_plan:
>
> - If the query plan that is specified by using plan_handle has been evicted from the plan cache, the query_plan column of the returned table is null. For example, this condition may occur if there is a time delay between when the plan handle was captured and when it was used with sys.dm_exec_query_plan.
> - Some Transact-SQL statements are not cached, such as bulk operation statements or statements containing string literals larger than 8 KB in size. XML Showplans for such statements cannot be retrieved by using sys.dm_exec_query_plan unless the batch is currently executing because they do not exist in the cache.
> - If a Transact-SQL batch or stored procedure contains a call to a user-defined function or a call to dynamic SQL, for example using EXEC (string), the compiled XML Showplan for the user-defined function is not included in the table returned by sys.dm_exec_query_plan for the batch or stored procedure. Instead, you must make a separate call to sys.dm_exec_query_plan for the plan handle that corresponds to the user-defined function.

And later..

> Due to a limitation in the number of nested levels allowed in the xml data type, sys.dm_exec_query_plan cannot return query plans that meet or exceed 128 levels of nested elements.

I'm confident that none of these apply to this procedure.  The result never has a query plan, no matter what the timing, so 1 doesn't apply.  There are no long string literals or bulk operations, so 2 doesn't apply.  There are no user defined functions or dynamic SQL, so 3 doesn't apply.  And there's little nesting, so the last doesn't apply.  In fact, it's a very simple proc, which I'm including in full (with some table names changed to protect the innocent).  Note that the parameter-sniffing shenanigans postdate the problem.  It still happens even if I use the parameters directly in the query.  Any ideas on why I don't have a viewable query plan for this proc?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetThreadComments] 
    @threadId int, 
    @stateCutoff int = 80, 
    @origin varchar(255) = null, 
    @includeComments bit = 1, 
    @count int = 100000
AS

if (@count is null)
begin
    select @count = 100000
end

-- copy parameters to local variables to avoid parameter sniffing
declare @threadIdL int, @stateCutoffL int, @originL varchar(255), @includeCommentsL bit, @countL int
select @threadIdL = @threadId, @stateCutoffL = @stateCutoff, @originL = @origin, @includeCommentsL = @includeComments, @countL = @count

set rowcount @countL

if (@originL = 'Foo')
begin
    select * from FooComments (nolock) where threadId = @threadId and statusCode <= @stateCutoff 
    order by isnull(parentCommentId, commentId), dateCreated
end
else
begin       
    if (@includeCommentsL = 1)
    begin
        select * from Comments (nolock) 
            where threadId = @threadIdL and statusCode <= @stateCutoffL
            order by isnull(parentCommentId, commentId), dateCreated
    end
    else
    begin
        select userId, commentId from Comments (nolock) 
            where threadId = @threadIdL and statusCode <= @stateCutoffL
            order by isnull(parentCommentId, commentId), dateCreated
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you get a query plan for each of the 3 queries?  Are those "tables" really views that may be calling functions?

Comment: Hey David.  I can confirm through dm_exec_query_stats that the plan_handle that isn't giving me a query plan is actually doing work, so I don't think it's the case that I'm just looking at some umbrella plan rather than the operational plan.

Comment: Whoops.  Good call David.  Though both tables are theoretically just tables, one of them actually a non-existent table.  FooComment got deleted somewhere along the way.  It didn't cause runtime problems because that branch apparently never gets used, but it looks like the lack of the table was preventing the query plan from being generated and/or shown correctly.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, perhaps the tables aren't really tables.  They could be views or something else.

Comment: Our shop ran into a lot of non-existent objects from copying database structures from one db to another.  Eventually we got a tool to detect the missing dependencies.

Comment: It's odd that nothing in SQL will complain about it until you actually execute that code branch.  Seems like something worth a warning somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

try putting `dbo.` or whatever the schema is in front of all of the table names, and then check again.

see this article:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html

quote from the article:

> As you can see, I refer to all tables
>   in two-part notation. That is, I also
>   specify the schema (which in SQL
>   7/2000 parlance normally is referred
>   to as owner.) If I would leave out the
>   schema, each user would get his own
>   his own private version of the query
>   plan

Comment: Hey KM.  That looks like good practice (and in fact we do have problems where sql trace will show poorly performing queries that run fine when I run them. . probably a case of each connection getting a different query plan).  But in this case we've been leaving out the fully qualified names from all of our procs and only this one lacks a query plan.